# What is the most efficient way to compute factorials modulo a prime?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, integers

Do you know any algorithm that calculates the factorial after modulus efficiently?

For example, I want to program:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
  sum += factorial(p-i) % p;
```

But, `p` is a big number (prime) for applying factorial directly $(p \leq 10^ 8)$.

In Python, this task is really easy, but i really want to know how to optimize.

Comment: Seems like the problem wants you to use Wilson's theorem.

For prime $p$, $(p-1)! = -1 \mod p$. 

So without using any programming language: the answer is $100$. Perhaps you would like to generalize your problem?

Comment: Can you state the problem more clearly?  Do you want to compute `(X!) (mod (X+1))`, or the more general `(X!) (mod Y)`?  And I presume that `factorial(100!)` doesn't really mean you want to apply the factorial function twice.

Comment: Even if you didn't have Wilson's theorem, you do have that $(mn)\bmod p=(m\bmod p)(n\bmod p)$, which would at least help avoid overflow issues.

Comment: Note that Wilson's Theorem applies only when $p$ is prime. Your question does not state that $p$ is prime, so what you've written is not correct.

Comment: [This looks oddly familiar](http://projecteuler.net/problem=381) :)

Comment: It's the [problem 381](http://projecteuler.net/problem=381) from the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/about)! :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*(This answer was initially posted by the asker [jonaprieto](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/1152/jonaprieto) inside the question.)*

I remember [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), and I noticed little things:

In the above program, it is better if I write:
$$\begin{align}
(p-1)! &\equiv -1 &\pmod p\\
(p-2)! &\equiv (p-1)! (p-1)^ {-1} \equiv \bf{1} &\pmod p\\
(p-3)! &\equiv (p-2)! (p-2)^ {-1} \equiv \bf{(p-2)^{-1}} &\pmod p\\
(p-4)! &\equiv (p-3)! (p-3)^ {-1} \equiv \bf{(p-2)^{-1}} \bf{(p-3)^{-1}} &\pmod p\\
\ (p-5)! &\equiv (p-4)! (p-4)^ {-1} \equiv \bf{(p-2)^{-1}} \bf{(p-3)^{-1}}\bf{(p-4)^{-1}}  &\pmod p\\
\end{align}$$

And you can find $(p-i)^{-1}$ because $\operatorname{gcd}(p, p-i) = 1$, so with the [extended Euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) you can find the value of $(p-i)^{-1}$, that is the inverse modulus.

You can view the same congruences too,  like to:
$$\begin{align*}
(p-5)! &\equiv (p-24)^{-1}&\pmod p\\
(p-4)! &\equiv (p+6)^{-1}&\pmod p\\
(p-3)! &\equiv (p-2)^{-1} &\pmod p\\
(p-2)! &\equiv 1&\pmod p\\
(p-1)! &\equiv -1&\pmod p\\
\end{align*}
$$ 
so, the sum is equal: $$ (-24)^{-1}+(6)^{-1} +(-2)^{-1}$$
and if you factorize in the beginning the factorials you get 
$$ 8\cdot (-24)^{-1} \pmod p$$
And, voila, inverse modulus is more efficient than factorials.

Comment: So basically $(p-k)! \equiv (p + (k-1)!(-1)^k)^{-1} \pmod p$. Neat!

Comment: Sorry but when I factorize $ (−24)^{−1}+6^{−1}+(−2)^{−1} $, I get :
$$
9\cdot(-24)^{-1}=\frac{-3}{8}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The example that you are posting is very closely related to Euler problem #381. So I will post an answer that doesn't solve the Euler problem. I will post how you can calculate factorials modulo a prime.

So: How to calculate n! modulo p?

Quick observation: If n ≥ p, then n! has a factor p, so the result is 0. Very quick. And if we ignore the requirement that p should be a prime then let q be the smallest prime factor of p, and n! modulo p is 0 if n ≥ q. There's also not much reason to require that p is a prime to answer your question.

Now in your example (n - i)! for 1 ≤ i ≤ 5 came up. You don't have to calculate five factorials: You calculate (n - 5)!, multiply by (n - 4) go get (n - 4)!, multiply by (n - 3) to get (n - 3)! etc. This reduces the work by almost a factor 5. Don't solve the problem literally.

The question is how to calculate n! modulo m. The obvious way is to calculate n!, a number with roughly n log n decimal digits, and calculate the remainder modulo p. That's hard work. Question: How can we get this result quicker? By not doing the obvious thing.

We know that ((a * b * c) modulo p = (((a * b) modulo p) * c) modulo p.

To calculate n!, we would normally start with x = 1, then multiply x by 1, 2, 3, ... n. Using the modulo formula, we calculate n! modulo p without calculating n!, by starting with x = 1, and then for i = 1, 2, 3, .., n we replace x with (x * i) modulo p.

We always have x < p and i < n, so we only need enough precision to calculate x * p, not the much higher precision to calculate n!. So to calculate n! modulo p for p ≥ 2 we take the following steps:

```
Step 1: Find the smallest prime factor q of p. If n ≥ q then the result is 0.
Step 2: Let x = 1, then for 1 ≤ i ≤ n replace x with (x * i) modulo p, and x is the result.
```

(Some answers mention Wilson's theorem, which only answers the question in the very special case of the example given, and is very useful to solve Euler problem #381, but in general isn't useful to solve the question that was asked).

Comment: 5! mod (14=2*7) = 8 (nonzero) yet n=5 >= q=2.  The quick observation second part is either incorrect or I'm not reading it right.  It seems the test should be the Kempner (Lucas, Smarandache) number https://oeis.org/A002034, which isn't quite so trivial to compute.

Answer (score -1):

This is my implementation use of the wilson's theorem:

The factMOD function is the one to call to compute (n!) % MOD when MOD-n is little against n.

Do someone know an other efficient approach when it's not the case (e.g: n=1e6 and MOD=1e9+7) ?

```
ll powmod(ll a, ll b){//a^b % MOD
  ll x=1,y=a;
  while(b){
    if(b&1){
      x*=y; if(x>=MOD)x%=MOD;
    }
    y*=y; if(y>=MOD)y%=MOD;
    b>>=1;
  }
  return x;
} 
ll InverseEuler(ll n){//modular inverse of n
  return powmod(n,MOD-2);
}
ll factMOD(ll n){ //n! % MOD efficient when MOD-n<n
   ll res=1,i;
   for(i=1; i<MOD-n; i++){
     res*=i;
     if(res>=MOD)res%=MOD;
   }
   res=InverseEuler(res);   
    if(!(n&1))
      res= -res +MOD;
  }
  return res%MOD;
}
```

Comment: Code isn't really on-topic, here. A description of the algorithm is much more useful because it doesn't require people to understand whatever language you decided to write your code in, and because actual implementations are often optimized in a way that makes them harder to understand. And please ask your questions as separate questions, rather than in your answer. Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, not a discussion board, and questions are hard to find if they're hidden amont the answers.  Thanks!